# Change the MenuItem icon in angular ui.gird

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grid, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

How to toggle the customizing_column_menu icons in angular ui.grid like shown below

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you attach a fiddle or plunkr where you want to show it

Comment: @pankajparkar see the example in http://plnkr.co/edit/Mkb3sDfCki4PRK6zXlpq?p=preview

Comment: I've added answer, kindly do check it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't found any best solution to change menuItems dynamically, Here is what I did for workaround

**Code**

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  rowHeight: 75,
  columnDefs: [{
    field: 'name',
    enableColumnMenu: false
  }, {
    field: 'gender',
    enableHiding: false,
    suppressRemoveSort: true,
    sort: {
      direction: uiGridConstants.ASC
    }
  }, {
    field: 'All Details',
    cellTemplate: '<p ng-show="grid.appScope.company"><label><b>Company:</b></label><span>{{row.entity.company}}</span></p><p ng-show="grid.appScope.email"><label><b>email:</b></label><span>{{row.entity.email}}</span></p>',
    menuItems: [{
      title: 'Company',
      icon: 'ui-grid-icon-ok',
      action: function() {
        $scope.company = $scope.company ? false : true;
      },
      context: $scope,
      shown: function() {
        return this.context.company;
      }
    },{
      title: 'Company',
      icon: 'ui-grid-icon-cancel',
      action: function() {
        $scope.company = $scope.company ? false : true;
      },
      context: $scope,
      shown: function() {
        return !this.context.company;
      }
    }, {
      title: 'Email',
      icon: 'ui-grid-icon-ok',
      action: function() {
        $scope.email = $scope.email ? false : true;
      },
      context: $scope,
      shown: function() {
        return this.context.email;
      }
    }, {
      title: 'Email',
      icon: 'ui-grid-icon-cancel',
      action: function() {
        $scope.email = $scope.email ? false : true;
      },
      context: $scope,
      shown: function() {
        return !this.context.email;
      }
    }]
  }]
};
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cdM5B0NNCnctNx02Eg4Z?p=preview)

Comment: thanks you, What you are given code is working properly but did not meet my requirements. my problem is to change icons when it show and hide...

Comment: @vamsikrishnamannem It is changing icon on click of it..did you checked it?

Comment: But I could't see icons in working Plunkr. It show title only.. I did understand you code.Thank you

Comment: @vamsikrishnamannem the sample plunkr you gave me also not showing menuItem, its wiered look at it http://plnkr.co/edit/Mkb3sDfCki4PRK6zXlpq?p=preview something is problem with css might be