# Dynamically Change the Grid Options in angular ui.grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have to show two types of gridOptions without using two grid's trying to change the gridOptions dynamically not working(one time working).

working example http://plnkr.co/edit/4QKGIB?p=preview.

```
$scope.grid1=function(){
   $scope.gridOptions = $scope.gridOptions1;
   $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
 }
 $scope.grid2=function(){
   $scope.gridOptions = $scope.gridOptions2;
   $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
 }
```

Comment: see it is working http://plnkr.co/edit/CvqzuRM4DzwxlbMs0kky?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you need to use `angular.copy()` while assigning columnDef to grid, which clones the array and set it to the `gridOptions`.

**Code**

```
 $scope.gridOptions = angular.copy($scope.gridOptions1);
 $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
 .success(function(data) {
   $scope.gridOptions1.data = data;
   $scope.gridOptions2.data = data;
   $scope.grid1();
 });
 $scope.grid1=function(){
   $scope.gridOptions = angular.copy($scope.gridOptions1);
   $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
 }
 $scope.grid2=function(){
   $scope.gridOptions = angular.copy($scope.gridOptions2);
   $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
 }
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pL77rKTXHQRf7UjWeNZY?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks you, if you know it please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643310/change-the-menuitem-icon-in-angular-ui-gird