# How to change sub grid url dynamically in ui-grid of angular.js

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have use case where I need to change sub grid url anyone knows how to do that. I tried solution given at [Dynamically Change the Grid Options in angular ui.grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678403/dynamically-change-the-grid-options-issue-angular-ui-grid/29683378#29683378)
,but its not working for sub grid.

Other option left is to use two grids, if anyone knows answer using single grid that would be great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do above by some work around like this -

Use the grid option like this

```
var handler = handler1; // Initially url1 will be used for subgrid

handler1 = function(row){if (row.isExpanded) { ... }} // Use url1
handler2 = function(row){if (row.isExpanded) { ... }} // Use url2

$scope.gridOption = {
...
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged($scope, function(row) {
      handler(row)
      }
)}}
```

Then change the 'handler' variable to 'handler2' or 'handler1' based on flow.

```
handler = handler2; // url2 will be used now for subgrid
```